# What is the syntax for SELECT IN statement for SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following MySQL statement that runs correctly in MySQL workbench:

```
SELECT *, max(invoiceDate) 
AS latestDate 
FROM goodsreceiptrecords 
WHERE (productKey, productIdentifier2) 
IN ((23,'Master'),(28,'Local'),(18,'Local'),(19,'Local')) AND unitPrice > 0 
GROUP BY productKey, productIdentifier1, vendorKey, storeType;
```

I tried using the same syntax for SQLITE but I am getting an error messase of:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: row value misused
```

What would be the correct syntax for this SELECT statement in MySQL?  Basically, What I am trying to do is select records that matches the values of 2 columns from the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) says:

> For a row-value IN operator, the left-hand side (hereafter "LHS") can be either a parenthesized list of values or a subquery with multiple columns. But the right-hand side (hereafter "RHS") must be a subquery expression.

But a VALUES clause can replace a subquery, so just use:

```
...
WHERE (productKey, productIdentifier2) 
   IN (VALUES(23,'Master'),(28,'Local'),(18,'Local'),(19,'Local'))
...
```